# Using buttons instead of <a> with pseudo classes - is it wrong?

Tags: html, css, input, pseudo-class

On the page there are links displayed with CSS as buttons:

```
HTML:
    <a class="button" href="#">Button</a>
CSS:
    a.button {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: $00f;
    }
    a.button:hover {
        background-color: $f00;
    }
```

I have some main concerns:
The href value is encrypted, thus will appear messy and ugly when the address shows in the browser when the user hovers over the link:

```
http://mysite.com/shjfgkh53hhsfd9ah390503hh35323j5hj35909ufudufdjj3
```

Also the href value will become significantly longer because *I can't transfer POST parameters* (everything's done by GET).

I could however, use this:

```
HTML:
    <input type="button" class="button" href="#" />
```

And then set the bg in CSS. **I'm just not sure whether using pseudo classes like :hover is correct and standards compliant here.** I personally thought :hover, :active, :visited etc were meant for links (i.e. a tags).

Clarifying this would really help me out a lot. Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK `:hover` should be valid on any element, though IE tends to forget that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They may not work correctly IE6, but all current browsers support this, and the spec doesn't forbid it: [See here for the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes).

What matters is what's supported by browsers.  Honestly, if they're using IE6 and something doesn't work...in this case it's not a **breaking** lack of functionality, your site works just fine even without.  I'd say you're perfectly in the clear here.